# xampp not install in ubuntu for php

Tags: 14.04, xampp

i am A php Developer and i am using ubuntu for php.

if install the xampp in ubuntu using terminal both way then produce the error. i am telling you what step i did it which step error produce..

1. first download the xampp in apachefirends.com
2. second open terminal and put cd ~/Downloads
3. third sudo su and after put password
4. forth sudo chmod 775 -R xampp-linux-x64-1.8.3-2-installer.run

then error start and error is-:

1. chmod: cannot access ‘xampp-linux-x64-1.8.3-2-installer.run’: No such file or directory

but xampp already download the our download folder.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Terminal and Navigate to the folder where you have downloaded the Xampp and then try the below command,

sudo chmod +x xampp-linux*installer.run

sudo ./xampp-linux*installer.run

This might fix the install issue of xampp.